# Vue transition within a transition ending the transition in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add a transition to a child div within another 'parent' div with its own transition, however there seems to be an issue with the child transition.

What appears to be happening is the child transition is getting confused with the parent transition and ending the transition in the wrong place.

The effect I am trying to get is when the button is clicked the Child Container A (in view) slides out left and Child Container B slides into view after Child Container A from the right.

I have replicated the issue here: https://codepen.io/BONDJAMES/pen/mdegmMe

How do I slide Child Container A out left, with Child Container B sliding into view after Child Container A, from the right, after a toggle?

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="viewBlocks">
    <transition name="slide">
      <div class="left" v-if="!MaxView">
        <div class="subContainer">
          <div class="container">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>

    <transition name="slide">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="subContainer">
          <button @click="toggleBtn">Toggle</button>
          Parent DIV
          <div class="container">
            <transition name="first-slide">
              <div v-if="!showMiniB" class="miniContainerA">

                <button @click="slideDivs">Slide A out - B In</button>
                Child Container A
              </div>
            </transition>

            <transition name="second-slide">
              <div v-if="showMiniB" class="miniContainerB">
                <button @click="slideDivs">Slide B out - A</button>
                Child Container B
              </div>
            </transition>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
     margin: 0;
}
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .viewBlocks {
     display: flex;
}
 .viewBlocks > * {
     flex: 1 1 0%;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .viewBlocks .subContainer {
     margin: 10px;
     background-color: white;
     min-height: 200px;
     padding: 1rem;
    /* prevent text wrapping during transition? */
     min-width: 300px;
}
 .viewBlocks .left {
     background-color: blue;
}
 .viewBlocks .right {
     background-color: red;
}
 .viewBlocks .container {
     background-color: white;
}
 .slide-leave-active, .slide-enter-active {
     transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
 .slide-leave-to, .slide-enter {
     flex-grow: 0;
}

.miniContainerA{
  border: green 3px solid;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px
}

.miniContainerB{
  border: pink 3px solid;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px
}

.first-slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.first-slide-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.first-slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}

.second-slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(0);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-leave {
  transform: translatex(-100%);
}
```

**VUE**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    MaxView: false,
    showMiniB: false
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleBtn(){
      this.MaxView = !this.MaxView
    },
    slideDivs(){
      this.showMiniB = !this.showMiniB
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of adjusting the css a bit

for `miniContainerA` and `miniContainerB` (using just div in example below) you need to anchor to the top. You can do this by positioning the parent as `absolute`, and the children (miniContainers) `relative`

```css
.viewBlocks .container {
     background-color: white;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
}

.viewBlocks .container div{
     background-color: yellow;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

then adjust your transition percentage (added 100% to your translatex values)

```css
.second-slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatex(0%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.second-slide-leave {
  transform: translatex(0%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Just one more question. At the moment the transition goes over the red border. How do I adjust where the transition leaves and enters to?

Comment: add `overflow: hidden;` to `.viewBlocks .subContainer`